# How do I print all characters after a space in a string?

Tags: c, string

A message is returned as `+OK (number)` after doing the `SIZE` command in `ncat`. I want to return just the number, so the string after the first space, and make it an int. How do I havr to do that? The string is stored in `char buff[1000]`

```
int getsize(char *file) {
    sprintf(buff, "SIZE '%s'\n", file);
    send(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff), 0);
    rsize = recv(sockfd, buff, 1000, 0);
    sscanf(buff, "%d", &resultcode);
    return (int) buff;
}
```

Comment: Show some code. What have you got so far?

Comment: Please remove the networking, sockets, and token tag.  Printing all characters after a space in a C string doesn't require those additional items (even if you are going to include them in your program).

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings are just starting points in memory (addresses) which if you walk them character by character, conventionally end with a null (a character who's value is 0x00).

This means that if you create a function that returns an address of the first character after the space, you have (effectively) a substring of the original string which contains the string after the space.

```
 const char* value = "Now is the time...";

 const char* firstCharAfterSpace(const char* input) {
   const char* starting = input;
   while (*starting != ' ') {
     starting++;
   }
   // first one _after_
   starting++;
   return starting;
 } 

 printf("%s", firstCharAfterSpace("Now is the time..."));
```

or

```
 printf("%s", firstCharAfterSapce(value));
```

should display

```
 is the time...
```

Comment: Whyyy that lengthy `firstCharAfterSpace` implementation? Isn't it just `return strchr(input, ' ') + 1;`?

Comment: @user3477950 Because sometimes to illustrate how something works, you need to illustrate it, instead of deferring that illustration to something that does the work for you.  I'm not promoting the idea that this is meant to be production code, I'm teaching a person about C, strings, and pointers.  It seems to be needed too, as they confuse their socket handling code with a simple string routine.

Answer (score 0):

I must sat that the question code needs to be much more careful about checking for errors.  However (following the question's lead):

```
int getsize(char *file)
{
    sprintf(buff, "SIZE '%s'\n", file);
    send(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff), 0);
    rsize = recv(sockfd, buff, 1000, 0);
    return(atoi(strchr(buff, ' ') + 1));  // Assuming that *buff = "+OK nnn..."
}
```

Comment: that returns 0 for me, for any file I put in

Comment: Oh, I had single quotes around %s, that's why

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
const char* firstCharAfterSpace(const char* input) {
   const char* starting = input;
   while (*starting++ != ' ');

   return ++starting;
 } 

 printf("%s", firstCharAfterSpace("Now is the time..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I print all characters after a space in a string in C?

You search for the space and print beginning with the next character:

```
const char *str = "foo bar baz quirk";
puts(strchr(str, ' ') + 1);
```

(If you want to convert it to a number, that's a different question; `man 3 strtod` and `man 3 strtol` in that case.)